# Django 1.6 {{ MEDIA_URL }} has a blank value in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am splitting my hair over this one. Have gone through some of the existing Q&A on StackOverflow, but it hasn't helped resolve my situation. In fact I remember sometime back during previous iteration of my development, {{ MEDIA_URL }} used to work fine. But now it is suddenly blank.

Here is are the details of my environemnt/settings (providing relevant snippets of code):

In settings.py I have defined the following

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/dir'
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In template file:

```
<img src={{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ employee.photo }} alt="photo" align=left valign=top/>
```

In views.py:

```
class EmployeeView(ListView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'CompanyApp/displayEmployees.html'
    context_object_name = 'EmployeeList'
```

In other related questions, I read people talk about two kind of solutions (neither of them seem to work for me). More details below:

Solution # 1 proposed is to add the following to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS:

```
'django.core.context_processors.media'
```

But when I do this, I get the following error on my dev environment:

```
[12/May/2014 23:37:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 93, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in   __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 49, in lo  ad_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
    TypeError: media() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Solution #2 I see being proposed is to return RequestContext in the views. But as one could see above, I am using ListView and it is automatically rendered to the template.

Any expert insight into how to make django recognize the {{ MEDIA_URL }} value again would be much appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. BTW how do I post code? It says in the instructions that I have to prefix it by four spaces. But it was a pain for me to use the space bar to prefix each line of code by four spaces, one line at a time. Is there a easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does ```{{ STATIC_URL }}``` have a value in the template?

Comment: Are you trying to access this in a local development environment?

Comment: Yes Static url has a value in the template. Works just fine

Comment: Yes in the local dev env.

Comment: I saw this same error: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-brasil/f-5WwMA2bac when you set it in the MIDDLEWARE list instead of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, can you double check if it's set in the right place?

Comment: @danielfranca, I was about to blindly say that I have defined it correctly in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, but then I checked my settings.py carefully and what a bummer it was - you were absolutely right!! I had added it to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES instead of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS :(. They were sections adjacent to each other and my eye didn't catch the fact that it was added at the wrong section. You hit the nail on the head. Thanks for helping catch my mistake. After correcting it, the {{ MEDIA_URL }} is getting the right value and it works fine.

Comment: Good :) I added it as a answer.

Comment: @StocknSurf sure, to accept an answer you have to click on the "check sign" below the answer points, then it becomes green :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you said, the error is the same related here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-brasil/f-5WwMA2bac the context processor is listed in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES instead of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Answer (score 0):

try add context_instance=RequestContext(request) in your view

```
def something(request):
   #your view goes here
   render_to_response('template.html',{#your_dict_items},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```